# make radio box and checkbox selection mandatory in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have two html tables in single page. One for source data and one for destination data.

User can select one element from source and multiple from Destination.

Source table has radio button for each  via angular JS ng-repeat.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 scrollableTable">
                                            <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped ">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="source in sourcedata">
                                                    <td><input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" ng-click="radio();checked()"/></td>
```

Destination table has checkbox for each  via ng-repeat.

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 scrollableTable padding-0">                    


<table ng-table="tableParams1" class="table table-striped">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="dest in destdata">
                                            <td> <input type="checkbox" class="check" ng-click="checked();radio()" /> </td> 
                                        ..
```

I want to check if user has selected at least one radio button and checkbox before making server call . Otherwise notify user to make selection.

Comment: Can you provide your codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I have used jquery and added class to radios and checkboxes in ng-repeat to enable the submit button.

```
$scope.checked=function(){
                //check if checkbox is checked
                if ( $('.check').is(':checked') && $('.radio').is(':checked')) 
                {
                    alert("in function");
                    $('.CopyColorInfo').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input

                } else {
                    $('.CopyColorInfo').attr('disabled', true); //disable input
                }
            };
            $scope.radio=function(){
                if ( $('.radio').is(':checked') && $('.check').is(':checked')) {    
                    $('.CopyColorInfo').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input

                } else {
                    $('.CopyColorInfo').attr('disabled', true); //disable input
                }
            };
```

This function works . But is there another better way?